# Yeoman CSS image paths

Tags: sass, compass-sass, yeoman

When I build my [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) project (nothing special, I'm only using jQuery and Modernizr), the images used with CSS aren't shown.

**My CSS-code**

```
.contact {
    background:url(../icon-contact.png) no-repeat top center;
}
```

**Output after building the app (no difference)**

```
.contact {background:url(../icon-contact.png) no-repeat top center;}
```

This doesn't work because the filename of icon-contact.png has changed to *f91724e0.icon-contact.png*.

How can I make sure that the image-paths are updated in the minified CSS-file?

---

**Edit: I've added my solution as an answer**

Comment: What is generating the image name?  It looks like a cache busting technique, but I don't think that's the naming convention Compass uses.

Comment: That looks like a sprite-sheet name, generated by compass. Are you using @import on the .png file somewhere?

Comment: The name is probably coming from Yeoman because it also renames JS-files, and CSS-files this way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Update (24 Feb. 2014)

You can fix this by adding `<%= yeoman.dist %>/images` to the `assetsDirs` of the usemin task. See http://www.github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/824#issuecomment-32691465

#### Previous answer (4 Mar. 2013)

There is an issue named ["usemin:css" doesn't generate correct image paths for relative urls](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/824) on GitHub about this particular problem. [Tak Tran](https://github.com/taktran) has made a branch of Yeoman and implemented a fix.

Here is how I removed the current Yeoman installation and installed the branched-version of Tak Tran:

```
npm uninstall yeoman -g
git clone git://github.com/taktran/yeoman.git
cd yeoman/cli
npm install -g
npm link
```

Source: https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/wiki/Additional-FAQ

With this fix, Yeoman wil rename relative image-paths in CSS and my question is answered. Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: You can fix this by adding `'<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'` to the `assetsDirs` of the `usemin` task. See https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/824#issuecomment-32691465

Comment: Glad it works! I have added my comment as an update to the answer.

Comment: Great. There were a couple other ways of going about it on that thread.

Answer (score 0):

In `GruntFile.js` you need to adapt the `usemin` task, so that references will be processed:

```
// update references in HTML/CSS to revved files
    usemin: {
      html: ['**/*.html'],
      css: ['**/*.css']
    },
```

Check if you have this task config.

Comment: I had these lines in `GruntFile.js`. I've added `scss: ['**/*.scss']` and this updates the filename in the final CSS-file. But the path is incorrect. I get `background: url('/app/images/icon-contact.png?1357818720');` but I want it to be `background: url(../images/icon-contact.png?1357818720);`

Comment: I can be wrong, but should you change the config of the compass task? The **images_dir** property probably needs to be '../images'. Or **generated_images_dir**

Comment: It had to to with a 'bug' in Yeoman. I've posted the answer that worked for me.