# GruntJS - wrong image paths after grunt build

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman, grunt-usemin

Grunt is messing my minified CSS and I cannot figure out why and how to avoid it.

To be brief, before the minification I have some background images like this:

```
.head-image {
  height: 380px;
  background: url("../images/head1_bg.png") repeat-x;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Then, after the whole process, I have a minified CSS that goes like this (snippet):

```
[...]background:url(/home/domo/projects/lp/.tmp/images/head1_bg.png) repeat-x;background-size:cover}[...]
```

The aforementioned path not only is an absolute path, but it's even wrong, since the images can be found in `dist/images`, not in `.tmp/images` (which doesn't even exists...).

A very similar issue is mentioned here: [yeoman#824](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/824)
I tried 2 solutions from that thread ([#17759188](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/824#issuecomment-17759188) and [#29137057](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/824#issuecomment-29137057)) but to no avail.

I even tried using the supposedly patched version of yeoman, as stated in another Stack Overflow question ([Yeoman CSS image paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14316643/yeoman-css-image-paths/14341950#14341950)) post, still with no success...

Maybe someone has already walked this path and found a solution that I haven't found on the internet.

**Edit:** I can add one more detail

image path inside HTML partials are not affected, like this:
`ng-src="./images/box_{{$index+1}}.png"`

**Gruntfile.js**

```
// Generated on 2014-07-14 using generator-angular 0.8.0
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // Load grunt tasks automatically
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    yeoman: {
      // configurable paths
      app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
      dist: 'dist'
    },

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
      bower: {
        files: ['bower.json'],
        tasks: ['bowerInstall']
      },
      js: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
        options: {
          livereload: true
        }
      },
      jsTest: {
        files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
      },
      compass: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
      },
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        },
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}/{,*/}*.html',
          '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ]
      }
    },

    // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: '0.0.0.0',
        livereload: 35729
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          base: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>'
          ]
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          port: 9001,
          base: [
            '.tmp',
            'test',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>'
          ]
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }
      }
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
      },
      all: [
        'Gruntfile.js',
        '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
      ],
      test: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
        },
        src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
      }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    autoprefixer: {
      options: {
        browsers: ['last 1 version']
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
    bowerInstall: {
      app: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
        ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/'
      },
      sass: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/'
      }
    },

    // Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
    compass: {
      options: {
        sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
        generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
        imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
        javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
        fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
        importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components',
        httpImagesPath: '/images',
        httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
        httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
        relativeAssets: false,
        assetCacheBuster: false,
        raw: 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n'
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated'
        }
      },
      server: {
        options: {
          debugInfo: true
        }
      }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    rev: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          src: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
          ]
        }
      }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
      html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        flow: {
          html: {
            steps: {
              js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
              css: ['cssmin']
            },
            post: {}
          }
        }
      }
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
      options: {
        assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
      }
    },

    // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
    cssmin: {
      options: {
        root: '<%= yeoman.app %>'
      }
    },

    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.svg',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
          removeOptionalTags: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: ['*.html', 'views/{,*/}*.html'],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },

    // ngmin tries to make the code safe for minification automatically by
    // using the Angular long form for dependency injection. It doesn't work on
    // things like resolve or inject so those have to be done manually.
    ngmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
          src: '*.js',
          dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Replace Google CDN references
    cdnify: {
      dist: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
      }
    },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            '.htaccess',
            '*.html',
            'views/{,*/}*.html',
            'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
            'fonts/*'
          ]
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/images',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
          src: ['generated/*']
        }]
      },
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        dest: '.tmp/styles/',
        src: '{,*/}*.css'
      }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'compass:server'
      ],
      test: [
        'compass'
      ],
      dist: [
        'compass:dist',
        'imagemin',
        'svgmin'
      ]
    },

    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
    // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
    // to use the Usemin blocks.
    // cssmin: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
    //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
    //         '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // uglify: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
    //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // concat: {
    //   dist: {}
    // },

    // Test settings
    karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
      }
    }
  });


  grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'bowerInstall',
      'concurrent:server',
      'autoprefixer',
      'connect:livereload',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'concurrent:test',
    'autoprefixer',
    'connect:test',
    'karma'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'bowerInstall',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'ngmin',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'rev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);
};
```

Comment: 5 views? how could this be even possible? :D

Comment: Perhaps this can be of use? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212153/yeoman-buildminify-renames-images-angularjs-ng-src-fails Looks like they *still* haven't fixed it?

Answer (score 5):

Some time ago, I had a similar issue with cssmin...

My config was:

```
cssmin: {
   options: {
     root:  '<%= yeoman.app %>'
   }
},
```

then I have removed `root` property and it solved the problem.

**UPD1:**
Also you need to add images to assetsDirs in configutarion for usemin:

```
usemin: {
  html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
  css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
  options: {
    assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images']
  }
},
```

**UPD2:**
About images with `ng-src="./images/box_{{$index+1}}.png"`, it is not possible to process them directly with usemin because there is no way to handle file revision in this expression...

But you can add separate map with image urls, like :

```
<div ng-init="boxes=[
    {src:'images/box1.png'},
    {src:'images/box2.png'}, 
    {src:'images/box3.png'}]>
    ....
    <img ng-src={{boxes[$index].src}}/>
    ....
</div>
```

And process those maps with additional pattern for usemin:

```
usemin: {
  html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
  htmlExtra: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
  css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
  options: {
    assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'],
    patterns:{
        htmlExtra:[
            [/['"]?src['"]?\s*:\s*['"]([^"']+)['"]/gm, 'Replacing urls in image maps']
        ]
    }
  }
},
```

Then after build you will get something like:

```
<div ng-init="boxes=[
        {src:'images/box1.xxxx.png'},
        {src:'images/box2.xxxx.png'}, 
        {src:'images/box3.xxxx.png'}]">
    ....
    <img ng-src={{boxes[$index].src}}/>
    ....
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still don't resolve the issue because the CSS now points to non existent images (e.g. the old images), not to the revved ones.
I'll add my `Gruntfile.js` though

Comment: Updated an answer, added fix for usemin configuration. Also you are using an outdated version of yeoman/generator-angular, this issue was already fixed in latest version

Comment: Almost there! Images in SCSS files are revved and their url updated. However images in the views are not, like this `ng-src="./images/box{{$index+1}}.jpg"`
It still points to `/box1.jpg` instead of `/somerandomhash.box1.jpg`. `usemin` should take care of this too... shouldn't it?

Comment: no, it can not replace dynamic urls...also, it will not even look for `ng-src` attribute at all (only `src` attributes would be processed)

Comment: but probably you can add own patters to match this images https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin#patterns

Comment: It will be harder than I initially thought, it seems, and I don't have a complete answer yet. Still, you helped me a lot with this and deserve your bounty. Thanks and congratulations :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Brunch](http://brunch.io)? They run a different node plugin for CSS minification than Yeoman/Grunt does. I have no problem with maintaining my "../" relative paths after minifying with Brunch. Try their [Angular skeleton](https://github.com/scotch/angular-brunch-seed), just drop your stylesheet in and run a build with

`brunch build --production`

to minify. See if you still have this compiling issue. Done in 5 mins.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I don't want to switch tool for the moment

Answer (score 0):

I've had the the same issue, eventually i was using the grunt.filerev.summary and the patterns js functions, which found the old img url and replaced it with the matching case in the grunt.filerev.summary json "map"